# Module isomorphism and trace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was reading the document [The Different Ideal](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf)
and there is a part on page 9, which I don't quite get.

We have a number field $K$ and its ring of algebraic integers $O_K$.
Say $\mathcal{P}$ is a prime ideal of $O_K$ above $p$.
Take an element $\pi \in \mathcal{P} \backslash\mathcal{P}^2 $.
Then, $(\pi^i)$ is divisible by $\mathcal{P}^i$, but not by 
$\mathcal{P}^{i+1}$, so $\mathcal{P}^{i} = (\pi^i) + \mathcal{P}^{i+1}$. Therefore, $O_K/ \mathcal{P}$ is isomorphic to
$\mathcal{P}^i / \mathcal{P}^{i+1}$ as $O_K$-module isomorphism by
$x \mod \mathcal{P} \rightarrow \pi^i x \mod \mathcal{P}^{i+1}$.

I understand until here and the following part is where
I am stuck on..

This $O_K$ module isomorphism comments with multiplication by
$y$ on both sides, so

$$
Tr (m_y: \mathcal{P}^i / \mathcal{P}^{i+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}^i / \mathcal{P}^{i+1} ) = 
Tr (m_y: O_K / \mathcal{P} \rightarrow O_K / \mathcal{P}).
$$

I would greatly appreciate an explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does trace mean where, when these aren't free $\mathcal{O}_K$-modules?

Comment: @AlexYoucis hmmmm. my apologies for the confusion. maybe I need to edit the question. I think they are vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $m_y$ is the matrix representation of a linear map, the multiplication by $y$. So it should be the trace of this linear map here.

Comment: Just check that the multiplication maps are conjugate to each other, and so they have the same trace.

Comment: @AlexYoucis All right! Sounds good! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $O_K$-module isomorphism $O_K / \mathcal P \simeq \mathcal P^i / \mathcal P^{i+1}$ can also be seen as an isomorphism of $\mathbb F_p$-vector spaces. The traces you are concerned about are traces of operators on $\mathbb F_p$ vector spaces.